# Jquery tmpl return HTML from function

Tags: jquery, jquery-templates

I have the following template

```
<script id="myTemplate" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">
    <p>${{html Name}}</p>
    <p>${Format(Title)}</p>
</script>
```

and the javascript function Format()

```
function Format(Title){
 return "<b>" + Title + "</b>";
}
```

and the actual data

```
var data = { 
    Name: "<h3>Tom</h3>", 
    Title: "Mr."
};
```

The ${{html Name}} works to display html tags contained in "Name". However, the HTML tags returned by my function "Format" are being rendered as text on my page. How can I return HTML from a function using JQuery tmpl?

Comment: Shouldn't you just use `{{html Format(Title)}}`?

Comment: @raina77ow - I had  duh! moment when I read your comment. I had tried ${{html Format(Title)}} and it did not work. Removing the $ sign made it work. Kicking myself now :). Could you retype your comment as an answer so I can accept it? Thanks

Comment: I would really also write here the following:
yes, you must write {{html someProperty}} here without(!) "$" at the beginning. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quoting the `${...}` [**doc**](http://api.jquery.com/template-tag-equal/):

> The values rendered by ${} are evaluated as strings, and are HTML
>   encoded. Any embedded markup will therefore be encoded. To insert the
>   unencoded markup in the rendered template, use instead the {{html}}
>   template tag.

So it can be fixed just with `{{html Format(Title)}}`.